# Laravel IF statement throws back error

Tags: database, laravel, if-statement

i want to write an IF statement in laravel which is something like this:

```
@if ({{ Auth::users->admin }} == 1)
    test
@else
    Test2
@endif
```

so i want to check the database to see if the admin is equal to 1 in the users table, but laravel throws back

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this if your view is visible for unauthenticated users:

```
@if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->admin == 1)
    test
@else
    Test2
@endif
```

Otherwise you can simply use: 
    @if(Auth::user()->admin == 1)
        test
    @else
        Test2
    @endif

`{{ }}` will echo the output in the view. While `@if(Auth::user()->admin == 1)` make an if statement. `if(Auth::user()->admin == 1)`.

Comment: it throws back Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->'

Comment: @RyanB this will first check if you're authenticated and after that it will check if you're an admin.

Comment: Ow, I forgot () after Auth::user(). This will get the authenticated user. @RyanB

Comment: No, you don't need the Auth::check() if the view is only for authenticated users. @RyanB

Comment: THANKS so much this has been bugging me for so long

Comment: @RyanB no problem, you can upvote and accept this answer if it helps you, so can other users see this solution.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
@if (Auth::user()->admin == 1) 
  test 
@else 
  Test2 
@endif
```